# Shopify theme app extension import npm package

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app

I'm trying to create a theme app extension for shopify, i'm currently working with an app block, i need to import an npm package, let's say moment.js so i did the following

```js
import moment from "moment";
```

but i got the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

so i tried with the require syntax

```js
const moment = require("moment");
```

but the result is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

this is the block template

```
<button id="random-button">
  random label
</button>

{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Random App Block",
    "target": "section",
    "javascript": "app.js",
    "stylesheet": "style.css",
    "settings":[]
}
{% endschema %}
```

What am i missing? I've just created the app with the Shopify CLI and added the extension, what's the correct way to import an npm package in an app block?

Comment: Can you please guide me how you solve this error? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I set up webpack and I made it work with it

Comment: How you setup webpack inside theme app extension?

Comment: It's challenging for me and there is no solution mentioned anywhere. Your help will means a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Okay it's not straightforward method but will resolve so many issues. For every npm packages, you'll have to add cdn scripts every time like old (HTML/CSS/JS) times, by going to your theme -> edit theme -> Open theme.liquid under Layout -> add necessary scripts there.
It's no way possible currently to add npm package and import or export tools.

For more details, follow the link. Scroll down to the last answer, you'll understand it. Guy has answered perfectly.

https://community.shopify.com/c/online-store-2-0/how-can-i-use-external-scripts-in-theme-app-extension-liquid/m-p/1592571/highlight/true#M3698

Hope that helps...